# How to create a route from query parameter

Tags: laravel, api, controller, laravel-routing, query-string

How to make a route and a controller to get a value from query parameter.

I want to get a `noTicket` value from the below link:

https://example.com/api/getdata?noTicket=1

My route:

```
Route::get('feedback_getNoTicket/{noTicket?}','FeedbackController@Feedback_APIgetNoTicket')->where('noTicket', '(.*)');
```

My controller, **but can't get the noTicket's value**

```
public function Feedback_APIgetNoTicket(Request $noTicket){

dd($noTicket);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this easy method :

https://example.com/api/getdata/?noTicket=1

Route :

```
Route::get('getdata/','FeedbackController@Feedback_APIgetNoTicket')->name('noticket');
```

Controller :

```
public function Feedback_APIgetNoTicket(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->noTicket);  // output 1
}
```